# Time returns always 0 when using a custom date

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to start a time from a start date for n number of days. When I use date (now) inside set interval function it works but if I use the date from parameter then the time is always 0.

```
let startDate = new Date().getTime();

startTimer(days,startDate) {

  let today = new Date().getTime();
  let countDown = this.addDays(today,days);
  let countDown2 = new Date(countDown).getTime();

  let x = setInterval(() => {

  let now = new Date().getTime();
  //let distance = countDown2 - startDate; //not working when i use startDate here
  let distance = countDown2 - now; //working when i use 'now'
  let hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  this.displayDate = hours + "h";

  if(distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    this.displayDate = "Expired";
     }
   })    
}

  addDays(date, days) {
   var result = new Date(date);
   result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return result;
 }
```

when i use startDate as 10 from parameter, the o/p is 10d: 0h: 0m: 0s (time always 0)

when i use any date other than now inside setinterval time in o/p will be 0 say 10d: 0h: 0m: 0s

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. No way to tell what values you're passing to your function.

Comment: Actually am testing the method with todays date always , startDate and now is todays date..!

Comment: where is countDownDays initialized ?

Comment: sorry my mistake it was days, i have updated the question!

Comment: Sure i will provide it am working on it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the init of x on the interval, and make sure you add a time that the interval is base off at the end of it...

```js
setInterval(() =>

// end of interval
}, 1000) // 1000ms = 1 second
```

and the function needs to return something... in this example i included the returns in a console.log() just to visualize it but removing that is easy.

```js
if(distance < 0) {
  clearInterval(x);
  return console.log("Expired")   
} else {
  return console.log(count_days + "d: " + hours + "h: " + minutes + "m: " + seconds + "s")
}
```

after those changes you should be able to call the `startTimer()` function and it should work just fine...

```js
startTimer(10, startDate)

/* OUTPUT
9d: 23h: 59m: 58s
9d: 23h: 59m: 57s
9d: 23h: 59m: 56s
9d: 23h: 59m: 55s
9d: 23h: 59m: 54s
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  what my intention is to show the timer until the final date ,in a webpage. So whenever i load the page the timer should show the remaining days, h,t,m,s..will this solution work like this?  i think i have to put the entire logic  inside set interval?? why my logic only works when i use now inside set interval function?

Comment: now only works inside of set interval because every time the interval runs now is reinstated as the current time, and subtracting the start time by the current time will give the amount of time is been running. which then on leads to returning the amount of time left

Comment: Ok, but when i tried this logic using startDate the output is still the same for me... time is 0, 0h: 0m: 0s day only displaying!

Comment: does it update in the console if you log it? is problem with updating the state of the timer on the page ?

Comment: let me check it !i will get back!

Comment: no, i have checked the console, i can see only day, time is 0!

Comment: this is working now! Thanks! today must be replaced with startdate!